Enum related error when updating from Angular v15 to v16
I recently updated from Angular 15 to 16 and some pages don't seem to load up at all. The error I'm getting is
"Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Cannot access 'HomeModule' before initialization
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'HomeModule' before initialization
at Module.HomeModule(src_app_components_signed-in_pages_promotions_home_home_module_ts.js:12:62)
at app.routing.ts:303:102". Upon tracing back the error, we found out the modules and component using enums were giving this error. This is one of the enums defined in a separate ts file as:
PurchaseType.ts:
   export enum PurchaseType {
      Bulk = 1,
      Single = 2
    }

All of these have been exported from a single file in the format of:
export * from './objects/orderingSystem/purchasing-type/PurchaseType';

app-routing:
This is how it's used in app-routing:
      {
        path: 'purchase-type',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./components/signed-in/pages/customerPurchase/mainPurchase/mainPurchase.module').then((m) => m.MainPurchaseModule),
      },

You would then used it as :
import { PurchaseType } from '@abc/orderingSystem';
    @NgModule({
  imports: [
    ABCModule.forRoot(),
    BCDModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'purchased-items',
        component: PurchasedPage,
        data: { bulk: PurchaseType.Bulk, single: PurchaseType.Single},
      },
   ]),
  ],

On clicking this page, the page doesn't load up and there are other pages having enums which show the same behavior. But if I change the path to original import from:
import { PurchaseType } from '@abc/orderingSystem';

to
import { PurchaseType } from 'dataTransferObjects/objects/purchasing-type/PurchaseType';

the routing seems to load up normally.
However, on stopping and restarting the server, the error pops up again.
I've tried changing the DTO to including 'const':
export const enum PurchaseType {
  Bulk = 1,
  Single = 2
}

and also tried exporting it as:
export enum PurchaseType {
  Bulk = '1',
  Single = '2'
}

Both of these didn't work. Is there some configurations when updating the Angular 16 i'm missing or anyone experienced similar issues? Any help would be appreciated! The tsconfig.json looks something like this:
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "../abcServer/wwwroot/dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ],
    "lib": [ "es2018", "dom" ],
    "paths": {
      "@abc/services/*": [ "src/app/services/*" ],
      "@abc/functions/*": [ "src/app/functions/*" ],
      "@abc/classes/*": [ "src/app/classes/*" ],
      "@abc/api/*": [ "src/app/dataServices/*" ],
      "@abc/analytics": [ "dataTransferObjects/analytics" ],
      "@abc/category": [ "dataTransferObjects/category" ],
      "@abc/customer": [ "dataTransferObjects/customer" ],
     "@abc/orderingSystem": [  "dataTransferObjects/orderingSystem"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
  }
}


please share tsconfig.json

I just added it above. For anonymity, i've used 'abc'

I think it's due to switching to ES2022 (and exnext), you can toggle the useDefineForClassFields to false to fix the issue. By default it's enabled.
You do not necessarily need to set target and module to ES2022, just setting the useDefineForClassFields to false alone is needed.
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    ...

useDefineForClassFields - Typescript Docs

Didn't seem to work for me. when I tried changing the target and module to es2022 and set "useDefineForClassFields" to true, it did give me a different error in a dto
"Property 'shipMethod' will overwrite the base property in 'abcDocs'. If this is intentional, add an initializer. Otherwise, add a 'declare' modifier or remove the redundant declaration."
import { abcDocs } from '../abcDocs /abcDocs ';
export class HotAddabc extends abcDocs {
shipMethod: string;
}

@LeoDiCap235 please share the code that gave the error, also just set the Boolean and keep it as ESNEXT
